# How to shard existing MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, scaling, sharding

I am using MySQL as my primary Database, but I need to shard it. How can I shard my existing database? 
What sort of algorithm do I need to get the latest records from tables in sharded DB e.g the latest 10 records from a table XYZ? Also, how can I sort the data according to a column value?

Comment: Very few people *actually* need to shard MySQL - it's the sort of thing you do if you're Facebook/Pinterest sized, and if you need it, you've got an entire engineering team to figure it out. Sharding adds enormous complexities and you're typically better off fixing indexes, optimizing queries, adding caching, and upgrading your server with more RAM/CPU. What problem are you actually trying to solve here?

Comment: For scaling a MySQL database across multiple nodes, we can use MySQL NDB Cluster https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-cluster.html

Comment: I strongly agree with ceejayoz's comments.  But if you would like to pursue sharding, you need to provide a lot more details on the application.  There are many approaches to sharding, but only a few are practical.  I need to understand the dataset to help you design _what_ to shard on, and _how_ to build a robust function for sharding.

Comment: In your further description, please include rough estimates of sizes you anticipate (eg, how many billion users.  Oh, wait, there are only about 7 billion people on earth.)  Also what types of queries will hit the data.  I would not expect sharding on time to be practical.  Sharding on user or some other entity is more practical -- and it should usually be an Entity for which the traffic is evenly distributed.

Comment: Sharding involves multiple servers.  How many do you have a budget for?

Comment: @RickJames i do agree with ceejayoz's comment. So to give you an outline my current organization is an e-commerce giant and we have been in the service since 2011. So in 8 years, our orders and orders_items table has grown enormously and is what giving us headache currently.
We do have a budget for 5-6 more servers. Hope to get a practical solution.

Comment: @SanjayBisht If you're an e-commerce giant, surely you've got a team capable of Googling up how things like `ORDER BY` work in a sharded setup?

Comment: OK, the sharding need is real.  And there is some hint of what the data looks like.  Now for the queries, which will lead to what makes sense for the sharding key.  I could help you review the options in his forum (or dba.stackexchange.com), but it would be better to discuss in more detail - mysql at rjweb dot org .  Also of note:  NDB _might_ be reasonable if most of the activity is little transactions.  Will you be requiring "reports", hence "summary tables"?

Comment: Also, are you currently using woocommerce or some other 3rd party package?  I expect that you have outgrown any 3rd party package.